# Iframe Relative Paths Challenge

Tags: html, iframe

I have a page and within the page I have an Iframe. The directory is as follows:

```
Folder1
   Folder2
      IframeCSS
          IframeCSS.Css
      iframePage1.html
stuff.css
parentPage1.html
```

In the iframePage it is referencing the `IframeCSS.Css` by use of relative link so `/IframeCss/IframeCSS.Css`

Due to the nature of the application, I am unable to change the link of the iframe page via hard code (Modifying the physical iFrame Html Page)

The overall goal is to get `iframePage1.html` to see `IframeCSS.Css` (and all other hrefs/src's) through relative links (`href="/IframeCSS/IframeCss.Css"`)

There are a couple of things I've tried:

1. Dynamically add a base path to the Iframe

   This failed because the base can only be added AFTER the iframe loads thus making the links act as if base did not exists
2. Create a container Iframe to get the HTML, add the Base, and copy over the Contents over to the displayed Iframe

   This failed because of the reason above, this method also causes issues with Google Map API's being loaded in as well
3. Go through the container iframe, using jquery, append the parent root to all src's and hrefs's to change the url

   This also failed.

What would you guys suggest I do at this point?

(The iframe points to the same domain AND the user needs to be able to navigate through the iframe)

parent HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="cmsCSS/CmsStyle.css" />
    <title></title>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="CmsScript.js"></script>
<script src="Insights.js"></script>
</head>

<body id="Dash">
    
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="topDash">
        <img id="something" src="img/logo.png" />

    </div>

    </form>
         <iframe id="dashBody"></iframe>
         <iframe id="iframeContainer"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: do you have access to the html for the Iframe page that you are grabbing?

Comment: @Martijn I tried .load with a div and when the user click on a menu item, it redirects the whole page. I need navigation to be split between page and section (Iframe)


Malachi I do have access. I can verify that adding a Base tag to the iframepage by hard code will indeed fix the problem. But the purpose of this app is to not do that.

Comment: When you did the ajax-to-div method, did you use the `preventDefault()` to stop the anchor?

Comment: @Martijn if I stopped the Anchor, how would the user navigate through the div?

Comment: Via ajax. Hijack them all, and all load them in the div. `$('#AjaxPage').on('click', 'a', function(){ $('#AjaxPage').load(this.href, /*  */ });`

Comment: @Martijn that answers the navigation. How would you answer the relative file linking question?

If I added the content via ajax, it would use the parent.html as the point of reference so I will receive an error as it will be unable to find the css file

Comment: @Martijn check out the link in my answer, some good stuff in that link about security stuff for your site using sandbox in your iframe

Comment: This would only work if there was some way to add the Base tag to the html and force all links to acknowledge the change

Comment: you are going to elaborate more on what you are trying to do and what the error is.

Comment: @Martijn The first comment you added really resonated throughout my head. There are places for iframes in html. it has it's uses and there is a reason for why it's still valid in HTML5. It may not be used as much for websites but there is a ton of uses for iframes in web applications. Saying Don't use iframes is just not correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

referencing a page within the same domain is simply not possible because even without the iframe, the page would not work with the relative file path:

```
Folder1
   Folder2
      IframeCSS
          IframeCSS.Css
      iframePage1.html
stuff.css
parentPage1.html
```

If you accessed the page by typing in `domain.com/Folder1/Folder2/IframePage1.html`
the page will not work because IframePage1.html is trying to access the css with:

```
href="/IframeCSS/IframeCss.Css"
```

which means that it is looking for `domain.com/IframeCSS/IframeCss.Css` and based on the file structure I provided, It simply does not exist.

What I was attempting to do was to simply somehow change the Hrefs and src's of the entire iframePage to instead of looking for `domain.com/IframeCSS/IframeCss.Css`, it would correct the link and search it in `domain.com/Folder1/Folder2/IframePage1.html` instead.

The solution to this is to put the contents of `Folder2` in the root directory, and create a new directory within the new root that contains the `parentPage1.html`. This way, file paths need not to be changed.

Comment: I have a similar problem like you. But in my case the iframePage1.html references css and assets in a relative way like `<link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">`. 
I have the problem that the when showing the iframe on parentPage1.html it would try to get `style.css` on the same level as parentPage, which seems weird to me...

Does anyone have an idea how I could embed a page similar to iframePage1.html in parentPage1.html with relative links working?

Answer (score 2):

using your same directory structure, this -

```
href="IframeCSS/IframeCss.css"
```

didn't work?  Without the "/" keeps it in the same directory.  Conversely, using "../" means back one directory.  So if you're trying to move backwards, you can just keep adding "../" (ex: "../../../stuff.css").

Comment: It would work if you could modify the html file loaded by the parent. In this scenerio you cannot. Regardless as noted above, I fixed it by making my application a child instead of a parent:

instead of cmsApp.com/website

It will now be:

website.com/cmsApp

Answer (score 0):

if you have access to the page that is being rendered inside of the iFrame, then all you have to do is add your link inside the `<head>` tags on that page for the CSS.  you should not have to do anything through the calling page.

you can view the page that is being called all by itself. so do everything for it all by itself.  JavaScript and all.

create that page first. then call it into the other page. `iframePage1.html` should be finished before you think about calling it into an iFrame in another page.  you should not have to do anything to it through `parentPage1.html`.

`iframePage1.html`  should have it's own `<html>` tags, it should be a self sustaining page that can be viewed in a browser with out an iframe.

I feel like I am going a little overboard. but I want to make sure that it is understood.

I can call google.com in an iframe on my page, and it will look the same as it does if I opened it in a browser all by itself.

**Found the Answer you are looking for I think**

check out this fiddle, the iframe on the right has clickable links that you can navigate inside of that iframe with.

I set the sandbox to allow only a certain number of things,  I didn't know about this prior to this question.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5wzG5/)

here is the page that I found that told me a little bit about the sandbox,  sounds like something that I will read about later

maybe something you should take a look at.

[Sandboxed iframes](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/security/sandboxed-iframes/)

I thought that you could move around in the iframes, but I was **WRONG** , but with Sandboxing you can do this!!!!

Comment: I used the CSS as an example. this will have to change ALL SRC and HREF's including images, links, etc.. etc.. not just the css

Comment: you should build that page first. all by itself

Comment: That last part about google brings up an interesting point..Let me create a jsfiddle to see if I can try to recreate the issue

Comment: you are talking about clicking on links and having that page show in the iframe?

Comment: I posted the parent HTML.

Essentially the iframe will contain the iframePage.html in which the user will be able to navigate normally within the iframe while keeping the topDash intact

Comment: have you tried to put something like google inside one of them, (or both) and navigate inside of one?

Comment: I get Refused to display 'https://www.google.com/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'. 

when I try to display google on the Iframe

Comment: I as well got the same thing inside the fiddle I went with the first thing that popped up in a search and it happened to be w3schools

Comment: Your examples are indeed correct except for the fact that you are missing one important variable in this problem. 

Fiddle is on one domain and W3c is on another. Each of these domains have their own roots. What I am doing is adding an html page from the same domain my page exists in. This causes the links to reference the root of the site, which unfortunately is not the root of folder 2

Comment: then it should just be a `src="folder2/iframePage1.html"` in your iframe code on the parent page. right?

Comment: Yes, The page is loading, it just can't find anything with a relative link (because it is trying to look for it in root)