# Assist with diagnosing PHP include, failed to open stream

Tags: php, filepath, require-once

I am attempting to move an old Intranet site running on Apache 2.2, to a WAMP setup (latest version) on my local machine.

One of the issues I have currently, is a `require_once` path failing to open, and I cannot determine what the cause is.

I have WAMP installed in:

```
C:\Wamp
```

I have changed http.conf and vhosts.conf to change the document root from

```
C:\Wamp\www
```

to

```
C:\Wamp\www\Intranet
```

This folder contains an `index.php`, which I can see being loaded correctly when browsing to localhost.

Index.php has an iFrame that loads welcome.php from

```
/site/welcome.php
```

This works, as the iFrame loads, but throws a 500 error.

Enabling PHP errors, the `welcome.php` page in the iFrame gives me an error on a `require_once`. The `require_once` is:

```
/site/login/config.php.
```

As you can see, I am using absolute paths here, so the fact that index.php is able to load `/site/welcome.php`, tells me it is loading the correct file from:

```
C:\Wamp\www\Intranet\site\welcome.php
```

I would expect then, my `require_once` with an absolute path to be loading:

```
C:\Wamp\www\Intranet\site\login\config.php
```

Which is a valid file path.

What is confusing me, is that the first absolute path I am using, seems to be starting from the document root, not the physical directory root.

The second absolute path I am using, does not seem to be starting from the document root.

Even more interestingly, if I change the `require_once` from:

```
/site/login/config.php
```

to

```
/login/config.php
```

It works?! I wouldn't expect it to, as that would suggest the absolute path I am specifying, is in fact a relative path?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19256735/iframe-relative-paths-challenge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this path (`/site/login/config.php`) makes sense on a windows machine.

Better than hardcoding the full file path, determine it on runtime.

E.g.:

```
define('ROOT_DIR', realpath(dirname(__FILE__)));
// because *nix and Windows path separators aren't the same (/ vs \)
define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR); 
// just for convenience sake, you could use DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR on its own.
```

Then including your config file, from **welcome.php** would be:

```
require_once(ROOT_DIR . DS . 'login' . DS . 'config.php');
```

I think that besides you are confusing the path that you use in the iframe declaration (which is a url path) with the path you use in the require (which is a filesystem path).

Comment: On the old machine, this used to work, when all the site content and the document root was stored on the root of a secondary volume e.g. E:\. I suspect the include path works in that instance, as it starts from the root of E:\ and finds the correct folder structure from there? Yes I think I may be getting the two path types confused.

Comment: What used to work? The code you posted in your question? The problem with hardcoding paths is exactly that: deploying on a different machine or a different architecture will bite you, so a solution like this is cleaner and more portable.

Comment: That's correct, my posted code worked. I think it is my naivety, in that I thought a PHP absolute path on Windows starts from the document root, not the file system root.

Comment: much better if you don't use absolute paths at all. and absolute paths on PHP are always filesystem dependent. There are not "document root relative" paths, unless you prepend the document root to a path. You could use `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` on apache, but better to just determine your application's root on runtime.

Comment: I would be inclined to agree with you, just was hoping to avoid doing a major set of adjustments, as this site is legacy and will be replaced by SharePoint in the near future.

Comment: These adjustments should be fairly minor. Just a couple defines and changes on the `require_once` calls, and you'd be done. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131338/discussion-between-yivi-and-eds).

Answer (score 1):

How i tend to resolve most of my include/require errors is by setting a variable path:

```
$path = dirname(__FILE__);
include($path.'/file.php');
```

This will prevent you from having trouble with different environments in this case being windows and linux.

Or even better:

```
define('ROOTPATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/'));
require ROOTPATH.'login/config.php';
```

Another thing, probably not causing your issues, but being good practice is to set the `DIRECTORY_SEPaRATOR`.

```
define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);

include(DS.'home'.DS.'www'.DS);
```

This will make PHP use the correct slash (either `/` or `\`)

Comment: Thanks, have seen a few people on SO suggesting this method. I was hoping to do a simple lift and shift, as this site is legacy and being replaced by a SharePoint site. Was hoping not to have to do any major rewrites if possible :)